# Change A data frame columns with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

sample dataframe

```
CountryName

India|Pakistan
Pakistan|Agansitan
Sweden
Nepal|Bhutan
```

Output dataframe witha new column

```
CountryName           MainCountry

India|Pakistan        India
Pakistan|Agansitan    Pakistan
Sweden                Sweden
Nepal|Bhutan          Nepal
```

I tried like

```
df["MainCountry"] =df['CountryName'].str.contains("[|].*","")
```

its giving true or false , can you help me in finding out how to get that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **`str.extract`**

```
df.assign(MainCountry=df.CountryName.str.extract(r'(.*?)(?:\||$)'))

          CountryName MainCountry
0      India|Pakistan       India
1  Pakistan|Agansitan    Pakistan
2              Sweden      Sweden
3        Nepal|Bhutan       Nepal
```

Or **`str.partition`**

```
df.assign(MainCountry=df.CountryName.str.partition('|')[0])

          CountryName MainCountry
0      India|Pakistan       India
1  Pakistan|Agansitan    Pakistan
2              Sweden      Sweden
3        Nepal|Bhutan       Nepal
```

Answer (score 3):

You could

```
In [87]: df['MainCountry'] = df['CountryName'].str.split('|').str[0]

In [88]: df
Out[88]:
          CountryName MainCountry
0      India|Pakistan       India
1  Pakistan|Agansitan    Pakistan
2              Sweden      Sweden
3        Nepal|Bhutan       Nepal
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.split` and `str.get`

```
df.CountryName.str.split('|').str.get(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

```
df['Main_Country'] = (np.where(df['CountryName'].str.contains('|'),
                  df['CountryName'].str.split('|').str[0],
                  df['CountryName']))
```

**Output:**

```
    CountryName       Main_Country
0   India|Pakistan      India
1   Pakistan|Agansitan  Pakistan
2   Sweden              Sweden
3   Nepal|Bhutan        Nepal
```